# Increasing the capacity of an electric baseboard thermostat

Tags: electrical, heating

The electric baseboard heat in my living room has a mechanical thermostat (bimetallic strip) that occasionally gets stuck in the "on" position.  I'd like to replace it with a solid-state thermostat, but the current thermostat is rated 22-amps, 240-volts, single-pole, and I haven't been able to find a solid-state replacement rated above 15 amps.  Is there some way to boost the capacity of one of these thermostats so it can handle the full load?

Comment: Is your heater actually 22A? What circuit breaker is it on?

Comment: @Ariel, It's connected to a 30-amp two-pole breaker.  The thermostat is controlling a pair of heaters wired in parallel.  I don't know the actual power draw, but 16.67 to 18.75 amps is typical for a similarly-sized pair.

Comment: That's actually an idea: Split the two heaters, and put separate thermostats on them. Might be cheaper than a relay. And if they are in different rooms you might get better temperature control. But even if not, just have two thermostats side by side.

Answer (score 2):

Use the solid state to drive a relay (that actually switches the baseboard) that is rated for the amps.

Comment: Just make sure the relay you're using is fully UL listed for the application